# await for indexdb event in async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, indexeddb

I'm trying to return a custom object from a async function that works as wrapper for a put using indexdb.

Using Promises this is easy.
However, using async/await became more challenging...

```
const set = async (storeName, key, value) => {


    if (!db)
        throw new Error("no db!");

    try {

        const result = {};

        let tx = db.transaction(storeName, "readwrite");
        let store = tx.objectStore(storeName);
        let r = store.put({ data: key, value: value });

        console.log(r);

        r.onsuccess = async () => {
            console.log('onsuccess');
            result.something = true;
        }
        r.onerror = async () => {
            console.log('onerror');
            result.something = false;
        }

        await r.transaction.complete;  // ok... this don't work

        // how can I await until onsuccess or onerror runs?

        return result;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

The ideia is to return a composed object... however all my attemps fails as onsuccess runs after returning the result.

I googled a lot and could't find a way to proper await for onsuccess/onerror events.

I know that returning a Promise is more easy as resolve(result) would end returning what I want... but **i'm trying to learn to make same code using async/await**.

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
function set(db, storeName, key, value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let result;
    const tx = db.transaction(storeName, 'readwrite');
    tx.oncomplete = _ => resolve(result);
    tx.onerror = event => reject(event.target.error);
    const store = tx.objectStore(storeName);
    const request = store.put({data: key, value: value});
    request.onsuccess = _ => result = request.result;
  });
}

async function callIt() {
  const db = ...;

  const result = await set(db, storeName, key, value);
  console.log(result);
}
```

---

Edit, since you insist on using the async qualifier for the set function, you can do this instead. Please note I find this pretty silly:

```
async function set(db, storeName, key, value) {
  // Wrap the code that uses indexedDB in a promise because that is 
  // the only way to use indexedDB together with promises and 
  // async/await syntax. Note this syntax is much less preferred than 
  // using the promise-returning function pattern I used in the previous 
  // section of this answer.
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let result;
    const tx = db.transaction(storeName, 'readwrite');
    tx.oncomplete = _ => resolve(result);
    tx.onerror = event => reject(event.target.error);
    const store = tx.objectStore(storeName);
    const request = store.put({data: key, value: value});
    request.onsuccess = _ => result = request.result;
  });

  // We have executed the promise, but have not awaited it yet. So now we 
  // await it. We can use try/catch here too, if we want, because the 
  // await will translate the promise rejection into an exception. Of course, 
  // this is also rather silly because we are doing the same thing as just 
  // allowing an uncaught exception to exit the function early.
  let result;
  try {
    result = await promise;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
    return;
  }

  // Now do something with the result
  console.debug('The result is', result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Josh. Lots of documentation refer to async/await as a new es6 way to implement promise based solutions.
I agree that using async qualifier to wrap a promise looks a little silly. However, the goal was not returning the indexedDB result as is, but a new object based on the result and adding some extra logic triggered by oncomplete and onerror events.

Comment: @dfelix async and await are how you *use* promises, but not how you create them. An async function return value is a promise. Even when you return a primitive number, it is wrapped in a promise. This is is why all async functions must be awaited if you want the settled value of the promise. You are making a distinction where one does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately you'll end up wrapping IDB in a promise-friend library, but for your specific need, you could use something like this:

```
function promiseForTransaction(tx) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    tx.oncomplete = e => resolve();
    tx.onabort = e => reject(tx.error);
  });
}
```

And then in your code you can write things such as:

```
await promiseForTransaction(r.tx);
```

... which will wait until the transaction completes, and throw an exception if it aborts. (Note that this requires calling the helper
before the transaction could possibly have completed/aborted, since
it won't ever resolve if the events have already fired)

Answer (score 1):

I can't confirm it right now but I think it should be `await tx.complete` instead of `await r.transaction.complete;`.

But a general solution that would work even if the API would not support Promises directly would be to wrap a `new Promise` around the `onsuccess` and `onerror` and use `await` to wait for that Promise to resolve, and in your `onsuccess` and `onerror` you then call the `resolve` function:

```
const set = async (storeName, key, value) => {


  if (!db)
    throw new Error("no db!");

  try {

    const result = {};

    let tx = db.transaction(storeName, "readwrite");
    let store = tx.objectStore(storeName);
    let r = store.put({
      data: key,
      value: value
    });

    console.log(r);

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      r.onsuccess = () => {
        console.log('onsuccess');
        result.something = true;
        resolve()
      }

      r.onerror = () => {
        console.log('onerror');
        result.something = false;
        // I assume you want to resolve the promise even if you get an error
        resolve()
      }
    })

    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

I would furhter change it to:

```js
try {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    r.onsuccess = resolve
    r.onerror = reject
  })

  console.log('success');
  result.something = true;
} catch(err) {
  console.log('error');
  result.something = false;
}
```

Comment: Resolving the promise on request success is premature. In the case of a write transaction, the promise should settle only when the transaction completes.